# Parsing an error message in JSON fails

Tags: javascript

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I get this response back from the API I am consuming and I want a popup
to show up on each error. For example: Desc can't be blank. I am using JavaScript.

This is the output in JSON.

```
{"desc":"can't be blank","value_1":"can't be blank"}
```

I tried this but it outputs every character, one by one.

```
for (var thekey = 0; thekey < response.length; thekey++) {

    alert(response[thekey]);

};
```

How can I output the errors?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first parse JSON into a JavaScript object, using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox):

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

The `JSON` object might not be available in older browsers, you have to include [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) then.

You cannot use a normal `for` loop to iterate over an object. You have to use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (var thekey in response) {
    if(response.hasOwnProperty(thekey)) {
        alert(response[thekey]);
    }
}
```

The properties of the object are `desc` and `value_1`, you cannot access them with numerical keys.

Answer (score 1):

If the `response` is a string you'll need to decode it to an object before you can do anything with it. Right now you're just looping through a string and printing each character.

You'll also probably want to use

```
for (var key in responseObject) {
   var value = responseObject[key];
}
```

since it will be an object and your keys aren't numeric.